# Inverse the interval of a negative integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

[Edited]
Given $f(x)=x^3+x^2$, we need to find the definite integral $$\int^{-1}_{-1.5} f(x)\ dx \text{.}$$

---

Let's assume the magnitude of the area between $x$-axis and the curve is $a$, definitely, $a$ is a positive number.
[the magnitude of the blue area is $a$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eYRO.png).
My question is, what's the sign of the definite integral $\int^{-1}_{-1.5} f(x)\ dx$?

My thought is:

---

The sign of the definite integral should be positive
because:

1. the area from $-1.5$ to $-1$ is under $x$-axis and above $f(x)$, so the definite integral should be negative, $-a$
2. after switching the boundaries, we negate the negative value, $-(-a)$, so we got a positive result

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: Are you asking what the sign of $\int_{-1.5}^{-1} f(x)\ dx$ is? or $\int_{-1.5}^{-1} |f(x)|\ dx$?

Comment: sorry for the ambiguous, by absolute, I mean the magnitude of the integral

Answer (score 1):

If you think that
$$\int\limits_{-1.5}^{-1}(x^2+x^3)dx<0$$
so
$$\int\limits_{-1}^{-1.5}(x^2+x^3)dx>0$$
then your thoughts are right. Generally $\int\limits_{a}^{b}=-\int\limits_{b}^{a}$